# Using cut on stdout with tabs

Tags: bash, cut

I have a file which contains one line of text with tabs

```
echo -e "foo\tbar\tfoo2\nx\ty\tz" > file.txt
```

I'd like to get the first column with cut. It works if I do

```
$ cut -f 1 file.txt
foo
x
```

But if I read it in a bash script

```
while read line
do
    new_name=`echo -e $line | cut -f 1`
    echo -e "$new_name"
done < file.txt
```

Then I get instead

```
foo bar foo2
x y z
```

What am I doing wrong?

/edit: My script looks like that right now

```
while IFS=$'\t' read word definition
do
    clean_word=`echo -e $word | external-command'`
    echo -e "$clean_word\t<b>$word</b><br>$definition" >> $2
done < $1
```

External command removes diacritics from a Greek word. Can the script be optimized any further without changing `external-command`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening is that you did not quote `$line` when reading the file. Then, the original tab-delimited format was lost and instead of tabs, spaces show in between words. And since `cut`'s default delimiter is a TAB, it does not find any and it prints the whole line.

So quoting works:

```
while read line
do
    new_name=`echo -e "$line" | cut -f 1`
    #----------------^^^^^^^
    echo -e "$new_name"
done < file.txt
```

Note, however, that you could have used `IFS` to set the tab as field separator and read more than one parameter at a time:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read name rest;
do
   echo "$name"
done < file.txt
```

returning:

```
foo
x
```

And, again, note that `awk` is even faster for this purpose:

```
$ awk -F"\t" '{print $1}' file.txt
foo
x
```

So, unless you want to call some external command while looping the file, `awk` (or `sed`) is better.

Comment: If I hadn't messed with `IFS` at all, can I omit it?

Comment: @marmistrz I don't understand your question. What do you mean?

Comment: If I didn't explicitly change the value of IFS, can I omit the `IFS=$'\t'`?

Comment: @marmistrz yes, you can. However, it defaults to space, so probably it won't work. Note also that we are saying `while IFS=$'\t'`, so that the `IFS` definition will just affect the loop. The original value of `IFS` won't change in the main session.

Comment: Well, it seems to work :) I'm reading line by line (and it works without setting `IFS`) and cut defaults to tab. Where should `IFS` be used?

Comment: Besides, the script is indeed quite slow. I uploaded it here: https://github.com/koreader/koreader/issues/279#issuecomment-105598429 Is there any way to speed it up a little?

Comment: @marmistrz you need to give more context. The `while` itself is not slow, it is probably what you are calling on every loop what makes it slow. Update your question with a more general approach if you want us to help you. Also: you are getting `$definition` and `$word` by using echo and then cut, whereas just `while read word definition` suffices